# Flex app with wmode opaque or transparent cause graphic glitches with IE on Windows

Tags: flash, apache-flex, swfobject, wmode, visual-glitch

I have a Flex app with has some HTML elements that need appear over it. To do this we set the the wmode to opaque (or transparent). However in Internet Explorer on Windows we often see graphic glitches when tabbing through mx:TextField inputs. The glitch is a rectangle spans almost the width of the app and is as tall as the TextField. The rectangle 'erases' the Flash content and displays the background of the site through it.

Scrolling the page a little bit, clicking off the browser, or even right-clicking on the Flash content makes the glitches go away (I assume when Flash redraws).

Setting the wmode to 'window' or 'direct' fixes the issue but then of course HTML elements can no longer appear on top of the Flex app.

We're using SWFObject to embed the player.

Has anyone run into a similar problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A work-around was to make an ExternalInterface call to change something about the div containing the swf. In our case we added a border-bottom to the div that was the same color as the background (#FFFFFF) and then toggled it between that and another almost identical color (#FFFFFE). That was enough to force the browser (which takes over some of the flash display) to force a redraw.

Comment: When do you do the toggling? Is it based on a timer which will do the toggling every few seconds?